# Dynamically Populating Javascript Array Based On CSS Class?

Tags: php, javascript, css, arrays

I'm in the process of building an app that currently contains a LOT of hidden divs that need to be cycled through.

Right now, there are only 5 divs in the cycle, but eventually there will be 20+.  Is there any way to get all of their IDs into an array based on their starting class in CSS?  Right now the default div has the classes 'show tab' and the others have the classes 'hide tab'.  I'd love to be able to populate the array with all the IDs of elements that have the 'tab' class.

I tried getElementsByClass, but I don't think I understood how that works - it just kept returning undefined.

The majority of the page is coded in PHP, so if there's a way to get the ID's using PHP and then pass that to javascript, that'd work too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated = )

Comment: First problem: class names cannot have spaces in them.  When you set the class of an element to "show tab", you give it **two** classes: "show" and "tab".  Try using "hide-tab" and "show-tab" instead.

Comment: What is/are the parent node/s of these divs? If they share the same parent, you can just traverse the `childNodes` and check against the `className` property.

Comment: I am using two class names.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: All the divs are contained in a form.  I can give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you all your divs into an array by class name using "pure" Javascript (i.e. out-of-the-box Javascript):

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
```

The divs could have any number of other classes applied, but if they have the "tab" class, they'll be included. The `tabs` array will then be an array of DOM objects. To access the divs' ids, you would do this:

```
var id = tabs[0].id;
```

Also, if you ever wanted to use jQuery, this would create a similar array-like object of divs:

```
var tabs = $('.tab');
```